# Trigger a mouse click upon an input type button from canvas

Tags: javascript, html, file, button, canvas

I'm working on a photo editor program using html 5 canvas, and I am using the  method to create a window that users can then utilize to find their image.  The problem is that I want to be able to do this when they click on a "button" within my canvas application instead of having an html button on the side or overlapped somewhere.  Basically I need to make it so when the user clicks on my button within the canvas, it triggers the click event on the  button. I have done some Google searching on this, but I haven't been able to find quite what I'm looking for...

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the onclick event, you would need something like this:

**Edit:** so you have a rectangular area in your canvas that should be clicked? if so, you define the 4 limits **leftLimit**, **rightLimit**, **topLimit** and **bottomLimit**, and execute this function onclick:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('yourCanvasId');
    button = document.getElementById('yourButtonId');
canvas.onclick = function(event) {
event = event || window.event;
var x = event.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft,
    y = event.pageY - canvas.offsetTop;
if(x > leftLimit && x < rightLimit && y > topLimit && y < bottomLimit) {
    var e = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
    e.initMouseEvent("click",1,1,document.defaultView,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,button);
    button.dispatchEvent(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: well it isn't for the entire canvas though, rather what I have defined within a canvas as a button, when I click it right now I can make alerts and things but for example: document.getElementById('fileDerp').click(); doesn't seem to do anything -_- any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind guys I figured it out... due to security reasons you cannot actually access the input type = "file" click events from javascript.